# Connecting to a Microsoft Access database using Processing

Tags: java, database, ms-access, processing

I'm trying to connect to a local Microsoft Access Database with Processing (v3.4 windows64).

According to this previous answer ( [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc) ) I've downloaded UCanAccess libraries from here ( http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html ) the current version is 4.0.4

It includes `ucanaccess-4.0.4.jar` and, under `lib` folder: `commons-lang-2.6.jar`, `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar`, `hsqldb.jar`, `jackcess-2.1.11.jar`

Here the simple sketch code I'm running:

```
import java.sql.*;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);  // Size must be the first statement
  stroke(255);     // Set line drawing color to white
  frameRate(30);

  try{

    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Dati/Profili/M030098/Documents/Database1_test.accdb");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tab_one");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }

  }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure to correctly import the 5 libraries within my sketch. Without them the catch block returns this message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/ ... path to my folder ... /Documents/Database1_test.accdb

If I import the 5 JARs coping them inside `Processing\libraries` folder and then add the line import `hsqldb.jar;` or `import hsqldb.*;` to my sketch the result is this console error:

> No library found for hsqldb
>   Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the sketchbook folder (see the Preferences window).

The only wired way I've found is to create a dedicated folder inside libraries with the same name of the jar including a library subfolder including the jar. All of them renamed removing any numbers and dash characters (see image).
In this way the libraries names are available under `sketch > import library` and, if selected, add several new include lines (48) to the sketch.

One of them ( `import org.apache.commons.lang.enum.*;` ) results in an error: `Syntax error on token "enum", Identifier expected.`

[image]

I've just commented that line considering `import org.apache.commons.lang.*;` instead.

As a result a new error occurs referring to line

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
```

> : `the type Statement is ambiguous`

Then I've looked for the library conflict and commented also `import org.hsqldb.*;`

Now it seems to work correctly, I can retrieve my table information but in a very messy way.

Is there a correct way to import just the 5 libraries?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by [Kevin Workman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53177663/1338032) drag and drop the JARs file in the sketch window is also possible and automatically creates a `code` folder within the sketch folder including the dropped files.

It includes all the packages and no more line of code are needed, anyway, this procedure has two drawbacks:

1. Due to the fact that behind the scenes it creates a `code` folder within the sketch folder import the packages only for one single sketch instead of the "global" library folder, and needs to be replicated for every sketch.
2. I've noticed two errors after importing the packages: one due to `org.apache.commons.lang.enum.*` which uses the dedicated word `enum` and `org.hsqldb.*` which has a definition of Statement object in conflict with another library. The drag and drop technique doesn't allow to select the single library to exclude in order to solve these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of to import a `.jar` file into a Processing sketch is to **drag the `.jar` file onto the Processing editor.**

[image: dragging jar onto Processing editor]

Do this for your 5 `.jar` files. If you're curious about what it's doing behind the scenes, take a look at your sketch directory after you do the dragging.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) is a tutorial on using libraries in Processing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Quick answer, it works. I believe it's the fastest way to import a jar package.
It has two drawbacks anyway:

1) the packages are only available for the current sketch and not globally.

2) it includes all the packages' classes and, in case of conflict error, is it not possible to exclude some of them.

Comment: @Mave751 If you need it available globally, then your question already contains how to do that. And I'm not sure what you mean about including all of the classes: both approaches will do the exact same thing in terms of classes. You need to use explicit import statements (not wildcard import statements) to avoid conflicts.